# CSS selector to act when a class exists

Tags: html, css

In the following html code the classB div can disappear dynamically

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="classB"></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="classC">
    <div class="classD"><div class="classE"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS selector that affects classE only when classB exists **using CSS only** or SCSS

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
.classA .classB + .classC .classD .classE {
    
}
```

Comment: Can `classB` only ever exist within `classA`, or can it be elsewhere (within what constraints, if any)?

Comment: Should be achievable without parent selector using :has and ~

Comment: `.classA:has(.classB) ~ .classC .classE {color: red;}`